# Error: Cannot find module 'https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts' in Supabase Edge Function

Tags: typescript, deno, edge-function

I'm encountering an issue when trying to create a new edge function in Supabase. The error message I'm seeing is: Cannot find module 'https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts' or its corresponding type declarations.

Deno Version: deno 1.37.0 (release, x86_64-pc-windows-msvc)
v8 11.8.172.3
typescript 5.2.2

npm Version: 10.2.1
Supabase Version: 1.99.5
Deno Extension Enabled

It seems like there's a problem with module resolution in your Deno environment. The error suggests that it cannot find the specified module 'https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts'. This module appears to be related to Deno's standard library, specifically the HTTP server module.

I would appreciate any guidance or insights on how to resolve this module resolution issue in my Supabase Edge Function, given the specific versions and setup I mentioned above.

**This is the folder structure**

[image]

I've tried the **deno install https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts** to see if it's a problem with the module installation. But the issue persists.